# Keep User and Group in same section in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have made my own `User` model in Django 1.8 with

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group, Permission

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

But it does not figure in admin any longer.

I have tried adding it to the admin page with

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, models as auth_models
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

UserModel = get_user_model()

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(UserModel, MyUserAdmin)
```

and it does figure in admin now but in a different 'section' than `Group`. How can I keep `User` in the default section in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `app_label` to Meta class of MyUser.

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
```

Official documentation on [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label).

Comment: Got the error

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'customuser.MyUser' that has not been installed`

with using Django 2.0, any idea? thanks